# Calling global functions from Angular with $window after loading new javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call a global function from within an angular function.

```
$window.genericFunction();
```

This works on functions which are part of the same js file but the functions I want to call have been added after angular kicks in, this is because angular is loading js based on user activity.

I want to update the value of $window to reflect the new functions available globally, I suppose? Is that possible?

Comment: Can you just use the actual `window` object instead of the angular service?

Comment: window.genericFunction() gives this error: TypeError: window.genericFunction is not a function

Comment: Is it possible you're attempting to access `genericFunction` before it's actually saved on the global `window` object?

Comment: I don't think that's possible the function isn't saved on the global window object. Way before this call I create a script element, set its attributes and append it to the head. When I do, it executes the functions it should on load correctly which involves a number of functions in the file.

Comment: I found a way to make it work but I have no idea what I'm doing really or why it works. I changed the function from: function genericFunction() {//contents} to: window.genericFunction = (function() {//contents} and now it works. Shouldn't javascript in one file be able to call functions in another file without this??